# What do empty curly braces mean in a string?

Tags: python

So I have been browsing through online sites to read a file line by line and I come to this part of this code:

```
print("Line {}: {}".format(linecount, line))
```

I am quite confused as to what is happening here. I know that it is printing something, but it shows:

```
"Line{}"
```

I do not understand what this means. I know that you could write this:

```
foo = "hi"
print(f"{foo} bob")
```

But I don't get why there are empty brackets.

Comment: f-strings are a quite recent addition to python (came in ~3.6), before that we used .format() or %.  the parameters of format are inserted into the {} in order, they act as placeholders.

Comment: It will not print `"Line{}"`.

Comment: See https://www.guru99.com/python-string-format.html or find a similar source.

Comment: Thanks PM77-1 this makes more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty braces are equivalent to numeric braces numbered from `0`:

```
>>> '{}: {}'.format(1,2)
'1: 2'
>>> '{0}: {1}'.format(1,2)
'1: 2'
```

Just a shortcut.

But if you use numerals you can control the order:

```
>>> '{1}: {0}'.format(1,2)
'2: 1'
```

Or the number of times something is used:

```
>>> '{0}: {0}, {1}: {1}'.format(1,2)
'1: 1, 2: 2'
```

Which you cannot do with empty braces.

Answer (score 2):

Doing `"My {} string is {}".format('formatted', 'awesome')` just fills in the curly braces with the args you provide in the format function in the order you enter the arguments.

So the first `{}` in the above string would get `'formatted'` and the second in that case would get `'awesome'`.

It's an older version of formatting strings than f strings (which I'm glad I started learning Python when these already came out), but you can equally write something like this similar to f-strings:

```
>>> template = 'I love {item}. It makes me {emotion}'
>>>
>>> my_sentence = template.format(item='fire', emotion='calm')
>>> print(my_sentence)
I love fire. It makes me calm.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way to interpolate strings in Python.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

The usage of string interpolations like this `f'Results of the {year} {event}'` came in Python 3.6.

Comment: Yes, but can you explain what "Line {}" does. The doc just shows the newer string formatting

Comment: In that link, about .format the docs says: "The str.format() method of strings requires more manual effort. You’ll still use { and } to mark where a variable will be substituted and can provide detailed formatting directives, but you’ll also need to provide the information to be formatted."